Blanket implementation for New Type design patter
I'd like to find an idiomatic way to locally extend the From trait to handle more inputs to a type defined in a library. I want to do this to allow for e: Error = "Message".into(), but a more obvious example is this:
I can do:
let i: i32 = 1;
let f: f64 = x.into();

I even can do
fn ff<F: Into<f64>>(f: F) -> f64 {
  f.into()
}
let i: i32 = 1;
let f = ff(i);

and have the compiler infer the appropriate From<_> when calling the function with whatever type.
but I can't do
let i: i64 = 1;
let f: f64 = x.into();


the trait From<i64> is not implemented for f64, which is required by i64: Into<_>

This is ok, as it would loose accuracy.
But what if I in my project know that the all i64 will be small enough, I don't care about loosing accuracy or want a panic if the u64 is too big ? How could I implement a custom From<i64> for f64 ?
I am not allowed to do
impl From<i64> for f64 {};

even though the lack of same exactly is the error message above :( (hence no ambiguity)
I found that using the Trait Extension design pattern does not make sense, as it's not possible and not viable to locally extend a specific generic argument  for an external trait.
Hence I tried to use the New Type design pattern be defining
struct M64(f64);

Hoping to create a type that works exactly like f64 but allows for into() from an i64;
So I tried to do  a "blanket" implementation for From to have the other into()s in place.
But I did not get the the Syntax right .
The closes I found is something like
impl<T: for<'a> From<f64>> From<T> for M64
where
    f64: From<T>,
{
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        let f: f64 = value.into();
        M64(f)
    }
}

This happily compiles, but does not translate into the correct generic into() for i32,
  let m64_3: M64 = i32_1.into();
   |                            ^^^^ the trait `for<'a> From<f64>` is not implemented for `i32`, which is required by `i32: Into<_>`
   |

I don't really grasp the impl<T: for<'a> syntax :(
BTW.:
when I additionally do impl From<u32> for M64, I  get the error message  conflicting implementation for M64 pointing to my code above, thus the syntax above does try to do something similar to what I want.
Any suggestions ?

Did you know, that there's the TryFrom trait which should exactly do what you expect: "But what if I in my project know that the all i64 will be small enough, I don't care about loosing accuracy or want a panic if the u64 is too big". You can do let x: f64 = 3_u64.try_into().expect("too big!")

let test: Result<f64,_> = u64_2.try_into();try_into() is not implemented for i64 -> f64, either.

"I don't really grasp the impl<T: for<'a> syntax :(" then don't use it for<'a> does nothing here, you can just delete it.

I just noticed, that TryFrom is not implemented for any floating types. Dang...  There's the conv crate which does the job. Take a look at it

I  found that the line  impl<T: Into<f64>> From<T> for M64 in fact works as a blanket !!!! unfortunately I now can't do impl From<u64> for M64 { any more, as it seemingly is already covered by the blanket, even though any appropriate error message tells me that From is not implemented for f64, and hence Into should not exist for u64 !?!?!?

For a trait you own you can either have a single blanket implementation or have several implementations for foreign types, you can't mix them. Overriding a blanket trait implementation in Rust rudimentally explains this, but I'm positive there is a better Q/A that I can't find right now.

I think I understand. In this area Rust is a bit less "friendly" than other languages. Maybe something still can be improved, maybe that's not possible due to language design paradigms for safety and no ambiguity.
To me i9t would make perfectly sense if it would be possible to do blanket implementations for a set of trait/Generic Attribute combinations and dedicated implementations for others. if there is no "override" (i.e the not covered generic attributes are explicitly excluded in the Blanket) (in my example by "Into" ) that should be fine.

I supposed impl <T: Into<f64> ... should exclude implementations for all Ts that don't feature  Into<f64>. Those would be those that don't see the appropriate f64::From, and this should hold for i64, Hence same is explicitly "free" and "should" be able to allow for a dedicated implementation. ... Just dreaming ... Where to post a feature request ?

But again, a future extension to the standard Frommight introduce ambiguity. Hence .... ?

BTW.: The conv trait of course does the trick with i64 ->f64. But VERY astonishingly as also does the conversion, that is is declined by ìnto()` (seemingly by reducing the accuracy). ... Weird !
